# Flatten nested objects with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm banging my head against a well trying to do the following with lodash. I have an array of objects with more nested objects, which looks like this:

```
[{
    id: 123,
    name: 'John',
    summary1: {
        count: 3,
        sum: 10,
    },
    summary2: {
        count: 10,
        sum: 20
    },
},
...
]
```

I want to convert each element of this array into something like this:

```
[{
    id: 123,
    name: 'John',
    summary1_count: 3,
    summary1_sum: 10
    summary2_count: 10,
    summary2_sum: 20,
},
...
]
```

SO basically I want to "flatten" each element of the array, in a way such that object keys are determined based on the main and subkeys. How can I accomplish this using lodash or plain JS?

You can assume there's just 1 level of nesting like in the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this without lodash (or another library) by iterating over the keys of each item in the original array, checking their type, and further iterating over their internal keys, building new keys to hold the right values.

```js
const array = [{
  id: 123,
  name: 'John',
  summary1: {
    count: 3,
    sum: 10
  },
  summary2: {
    count: 10,
    sum: 20
  }
}];


let newArray = array.map(item => {
  let newObj = {};

  Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
    if (typeof item[key] === 'object') {
      Object.keys(item[key]).forEach(innerKey => {
        newObj[`${key}_${innerKey}`] = item[key][innerKey];
      });
    } else {
      newObj[key] = item[key];
    }
  });

  return newObj;
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Granted, this isn't necessarily very pretty or flexible (following your assumption of a single level deep).

Comment: Since `typeof null` is still `object`, you may want to add this to the condition as well to avoid bugs

Answer (score 12):

You can simply use the npm package [flat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat).

```
import flat from 'flat';

const array = [
  {
    a: 'a',
    b: {
      bb: 'bb',
    },
    c: {
      cc1: 'cc1',
      cc: {
        ccc: 'ccc',
        ccd: 'ccd',
      },
    },
  },
  // ...
];

const flattenedArray = array.map(flat);

/*
  flattenedArray === [
    {
      a: 'a',
      b.bb: 'bb',
      c.cc1: 'cc1',
      c.cc.ccc: 'ccc',
      c.cc.ccd: 'ccd',
    },
    // ...
  ]
*/
```

And if you want to implement it yourself, here's my implementation of `flat`:

```
const flat = (obj, concatenator = '.') => (
  Object.keys(obj).reduce(
    (acc, key) => {
      if (typeof obj[key] !== 'object' || !obj[key]) {
        return {
          ...acc,
          [key]: obj[key],
        };
      }

      const flattenedChild = flat(obj[key], concatenator);

      return {
        ...acc,
        ...Object.keys(flattenedChild).reduce((childAcc, childKey) => ({ ...childAcc, [`${key}${concatenator}${childKey}`]: flattenedChild[childKey] }), {}),
      };
    },
    {},
  )
);

const flattenedArray = array.map(o => flat(o));
```

Those solutions will work with any depth.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [flat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat)

```js
import { flatten } from 'flat'

flatten({
    key1: {
        keyA: 'valueI'
    },
    key2: {
        keyB: 'valueII'
    },
    key3: { a: { b: { c: 2 } } }
})

// {
//   'key1.keyA': 'valueI',
//   'key2.keyB': 'valueII',
//   'key3.a.b.c': 2
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are solution for processing nested objects as well without loadash

```
function objectToPathsValues(item: any): { [key: string]: any } {

    let newObj = {};
    let path = '';

    flattingNestedObject(item,path, newObj);

    return newObj;

}
function flattingNestedObject(item: any,path: string, output: { [key: string]: any }): void {
    Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
        const combinedPath = path ? `${path}.${key}` : key;
        if (typeof item[key] === 'object') {

            flattingNestedObject(item[key],combinedPath, output);
        } else {
            output[combinedPath] = item[key];
        }
    });
}
```

and just call

```
objectToPathsValues(yourHugeObjectWithNestedObjectChildren);
```

The only one remark your object has not have circular nested objects.